# Show condition button in email template odoo 12

Tags: templates, if-statement, href, odoo

I override the survey template. And I added the condition to show button according to if and else condition. This condition based on one selection field in survey management. But when I try to send email it shows me error following error "The content of the text doesn't contain '**URL**'. **URL** is automatically converted into the special URL of the survey."

```
class InheritedSurvey(models.Model):
_inherit = 'survey.survey'

survey_type = fields.Selection([('inhouse', 'In House'),
                                ('3rd_party', '3rd Party')], store=True, default='inhouse')
```

Email template if and else condition:

```
<record id="survey.email_template_survey" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Survey: Send by email</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_survey_survey"/>
            <field name="subject">${object.title}: Survey</field>
            <field name="body_html" type="html">
                <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">
                    <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">
                        Hello
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        We are conducting a survey, and your response would be appreciated.
                        % if object.survey_type == 'inhouse':
                        <div style="margin: 16px 0px 16px 0px;">
                            <a href="__URL__"
                               style="background-color: #875A7B; padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; font-size:13px;">
                                Start Survey
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        % else:
                        <div style="margin: 16px 0px 16px 0px;">
                            <a t-attf-href="'%s&%s' % (__URL__, 1231)"
                               style="background-color: #875A7B; padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; font-size:13px;">
                                Testtttttttttttttt Survey
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        Thanks for your participation!
                    </p>
                </div>
            </field>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="user_signature" eval="False"/>
        </record>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First guess try `<a t-attf-href="'__URL__&%s' % (1231,)"` instead of your approach.